# Google Analytics end users proper notice

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

-i implemented Google Analytics for android
-in Measurement Protocol / SDK / User-ID Policy
  google says **You will give your end users proper notice about the implementations and features of Google Analytics you use**

-is this need to show user?
-which is best way to ask user? like popup first time or any any other way suggest

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are really concerned about it, you should consult a lawyer. I'm not a lawyer so take this for what it's worth (the opinion of a random internet stranger who is not a lawyer), but *my* interpretation would be to include a notice of it wherever I normally include my own Terms of Service (ToS).

Example:

- Whatever page or medium where the user can first download the app, if I am able to (e.g. on my own website), I would have my ToS displayed with a checkbox to check before download will begin.
- When user installs the app for the first time, I would show same ToS with checkbox for them to accept before proceeding with install or first ever app start
- Whenever there is an update to the app, show the same ToS w/ checkbox for them to accept (if the update changes any functionality or adds new tracking, etc..)
- I'd also have the ToS listed as a menu item somewhere like in an Info or About section. e.g. a link to it on my website.

Answer (score 0):

It's concern me too. So I googled and found this [site](http://support.andromo.com/kb/common-questions/how-to-use-google-analytics-in-your-application) and solution was to add something like the following text to your Google Play descriptions:

(This application uses Google Analytics to anonymously track usage data within the application.)

Than you must allow the user to opt out of analytics in the application Settings. And show notice in the app's About dialog when analytics is enabled.